# group by with 'pre-defined row'

Tags: sql-server, group-by

Say I have to following PaymentTransaction Table:

```
 ID       Amount    PayMethodID
 ----------------------------
 10254     100        1      
 15789     150        1      
 15790     200        0      
 16954     300        0      
 17864     400        1      
 19364     500        1
```

```
 PayMethodID  Desc
 ----------------------------
 0            CASH     
 1            VISA   
 2            MASTER      
 3            AMEX     
 4            ETC
```

I can simply use a `group by` to group the PayMethodID under 1 and 0.

What i am trying to do is to show also the non-exist PayMethodID under GROUP BY

My current result with simple group by statement is

```
PayMethodID   TotalAmount
-------------------------
0             500
1             1150
```

Expected result (to show 0 if its not exits in the transaction table):

```
PayMethodID   TotalAmount
-------------------------
0             500
1             1150
2             0
3             0
4             0
```

This might be a simple and duplicated question, but i just cant find the keyword to search around. I would remove this post if you can find me any duplication. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN`, so all rows from leftmost table (*TableA*) will be shown whether it has a matching values on the other table or not.

```
SELECT  a.PayMethodID,
        TotalAmount = ISNULL(SUM(b.Amount), 0)
FROM    TableA AS a                  -- <== contains list of card type
        LEFT JOIN TableB AS b        -- <== contains the payment list
            ON a.PayMethodID = b.PayMethodID
GROUP   BY a.PayMethodID
```

Comment: Thanks, so now i know the keyword should be `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

A regular OUTER (LEFT) JOIN will give you all rows from the PayMethod table no matter if they exist in the PaymentTransaction table, the rest of the sums being NULL. You can then use a COALESCE to make the null rows zero;

```
SELECT pm.PayMethodID, COALESCE(SUM(pt.Amount), 0) TotalAmount
FROM PayMethod pm
LEFT JOIN PaymentTransaction pt
  ON pm.PayMethodID = pt.PayMethodID
GROUP BY pm.PayMethodID
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d4afd/1).

Comment: Thanks, so now i know the keyword should be `LEFT JOIN`